# VSTO Outlook: Differenciate between a manual and automatic send

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Is there any way to recognize if the ItemSend event is fired as a result of sending a message from the compose window or as a result of an automatic send performed by Outlook itself (e.g. when messages in the outbox are sent)?

Answer (score 1):

No, the `ItemSend` event doesn't provide such information. Also you may find the [Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.send(even)) event of Outlook items working the same, it is fired when the user selects the `Send` action for an item, or when the `Send` method is called for the item, which is an instance of the parent object. For handling the item-level events you can [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector). So, that you will be aware when and when events are fired (if any inspector was opened before).

> when messages in the outbox are sent)

Both events (`ItemSend` and `Send`) are fired when the item is submitted and before moved to the Outbox folder. But you may try to check the parent folder of the item, but that can't give you any definitive answer.

If you really need to know when the user clicked the `Send` button you may consider using clicks on the Send button in Outlook by using Windows API techniques such as subclassing. The same mechanism can be used for handling keyboard shortcuts in Outlook.

Comment: Previously answer provided seems correct. Currently there is no way to differentiate between automatic send and manual send. Also, both send and ItemSend are triggered when the user clicks on the send button, before the item is moved.

Comment: Did I mention that it is possible?

Comment: No, you did not mention that. We said your answer is correct and it is not possible.

Comment: It seems I have misunderstood your post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Application.ItemSend` event, use `MailItem.Send` event. You can trap `Application.Inspectors.NewInspector` event to hook into new `Inspector`, then set up event handler on `Inspector.CurrentItem`. Keep in mind that there can be multiple inspectors open, and you'd need to unsubscribe from the events when the inspector is closed (`Inspector.Close` event). You can do the same for the the inline items (`Explorer.InlineResponse/InlineResponseClose` events).

Keep in mind that `Application.ItemSend` event fires when a message is sent either by the user or programmatically, it does *not* fire when an item is moved away from the Outbox folder after asynchronous message submission completes some time later.

You can see which events fire and when in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - e.g., click Application button, go to the Events tab and see events fire.